# Locations does not change even IP and Geo is specified

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, universal-analytics

We are using `universal-analytics` on `nodejs` to track `Google Analytics`. We have to use back end to track *(Just some requirements)*. The code below works but the Location shows `United States` on GA dashboard. Maybe our server is on the US.

Even if Ill put the IP address and hardcode `geoid` it is still show on the US.

```
var visitor = ua('UA-XXX-XX', {
  uid: 'as8ek9nlll3333',
  uip: ipaddress,       //The IP address is correct
  geoid: "ID"
});

visitor.pageview("/", "http://bla.com", "TEST", function(err) {
  console.log("CALLBACK");
  console.log(err);     //Getting null
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `The IP address is correct` whose IP is this? Yours or the "visitors"?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, visitors IP Address. Not the server

Answer (score -1):

Do you have an NGINX setup in front of the server as a reverse proxy? If it is, then you need to forward the client IP along with the request from the NGINX server.